# Android activity doesn't show up

Tags: android

I'm trying to start an activity (Act2) from another activity(Act1), and it doesn't happen like it should.

In the debugger, I can see that as a result of calling startActivity() the method **onCreate()** of act2 is **called 3 times** (!!...), no error shows, or exception caught, and unfortunatly the desired UI doesn't show.

for trying to understand better where is the problem, I run the next 2 tests that showed expected normal behavior:

1. when I modify Act1 to start Act3 (instead of Act2, just for
   understanding if its a problemof Act1), then act3 shows its UI as expected.
2. when Act4 start Act2, it runs as expected, and show the UI on the screen.

As to the code, I start the activity in the common way of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Anyone faced such thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read through the documentation on the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

OnCreate will only be called one time for each lifetime of the Activity.  However, there are a number of situations that can cause your activity to be killed and brought back to life.  Thus, onCreate will be called again.

To support this properly, you can save state information in onSaveInstanceState and restore it fron the state bundle you get in on create.

Comment: thanls for the quick response.

Comment: I hope it would have helped you.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. but I already saw the lifecycle, and  yet I don't undrestand what causes my activity running fine when its called from different context (and from current context - valid activating another activity)

Comment: Well, I am extending existing application, and there is a code that was called which caused this behavior of calling Act1 few times, due to some complicated context.
So I fixed the context, and the bug doesn't occure now. yet, I don't know the way of finding "who activated me?" (besides of searching in the code "startActivity(Act1intent)") Thanks for the answer anyway!